# Strange behavior of urllib.request in two different cases while webscraping

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, urllib, http-status-code-403

I am trying to download bhavcopy of NSE EoD data for last 15 years using web scraping through urllib.request.

I am seeing that urllib.request is behaving strangely, it is working in one case but in another case it is throwing me error 403 Access Denies ..

I used the HTTP Headers for masking but in one case it is failing ..

Here is the code

```
import urllib.request
def downloadCMCSV(year="2001",mon="JAN",dd="01"):
    #baseurl = "https://www.nseindia.com"
    headers = {'Host':'www.nseindia.com:443',
               'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
               'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
               #'Cookie':'NSE-TEST-1=1809850378.20480.0000; pointer=1; sym1=ONGC; pointerfo=1; underlying1=ONGC; instrument1=FUTSTK; optiontype1=-; expiry1=27OCT2016; strikeprice1=-',
               'Cookie':'NSE-TEST-1=1809850378.20480.0000; pointer=1; sym1=ONGC; pointerfo=1; underlying1=ONGC; instrument1=FUTSTK; optiontype1=-; expiry1=27OCT2016; strikeprice1=-; JSESSIONID=B4CA0543FF4C33FD9EA9D18B95238DB4',
               'Referer':'Referer: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm',
               'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
               'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
    filename = "cm%s%s%sbhav.csv" % (dd,mon,year)
    urlcm = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/%s/%s/%s.zip" % (year, mon, filename)
    print(urlcm)
    request = urllib.request.Request(urlcm, headers = headers)
    #print(dir(request))
    #print(request.headers)
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 404:
            print("Bhavcopy not available for", year, mon, dd)
            return
        print(e.code)
        print(e.read())  
        return
    if response.code == 200:
        print("The response is good", response.length)
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #getAll()
    downloadCMCSV('2001','JAN', '01')
    downloadCMCSV('2016','JAN', '01')
```

Got Output as below

```
https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2001/JAN/cm01JAN2001bhav.csv.zip
403
b'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;nseindia&#46;com&#47;content&#47;historical&#47;EQUITIES&#47;2001&#47;JAN&#47;cm01JAN2001bhav&#46;csv&#46;zip" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;33210f17&#46;1476700779&#46;13b4f615\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2016/JAN/cm01JAN2016bhav.csv.zip
The response is good 58943
```

Could you guys please help me what mistake I am doing ?

Comment: https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2001/JAN/cm01JAN2001bhav.csv.zip 
A simple hit on this url also gives 403. No doubt it gives the same on `urllib.request`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with the `urlib.request` but with the very resource you're trying to scrape. Maybe it's just how the website works and there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: When i go through this link....  [link](https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm)  and search by typing 'Bhavcopy' and select date as '2001-01-01' and when I click on link it work ........can you guide me how i should approach this on python ?

Answer (score 1):

Pass a *user-agent* , `'Accept': '*/*'` and the *referer* headers:

```
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2001/JAN/cm01JAN2001bhav.csv.zip"
r = request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'mybot', 'Accept': '*/*',
                                  "Referer": "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm"})

print(request.urlopen(r))
```

You don't need cookies or anything else set.